# Power over coax circuit clarification needed

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog, filter, camera

The below image is taken from [DS90UB913A-CXEVM Serializer Board Schematic](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snlu135b/snlu135b.pdf).  T he complete schematic is on page 21. The PoC network is enclosed in an orange box. You can see that two resistors (R28,R71) are connected in parallel with inductors. They are used to lower the Q.

I have some questions regarding this circuit.

1. How do R28 and R71 reduce the Q?
2. How should I design the PoC network?
3. Do we need 50 Ohm connectors for DOUT0+ and DOUT0-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the presence of the two 1000 ohm resistors (yellow boxes) in the supply feed (R29 and L4): -

[image]

………I think it's fairly irrelevant having resistors in parallel with L10 and L2 but, they will reduce the Q of the inductors because you can **transform** a parallel RL to a series RL if you know the operating frequency at which they are to be used: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.emcourse.com/converting-parallel-rl-circuits-their-easier-work-series-equivalents.html).

And, once you have the equivalent series circuit, it's easy to see how Q is reduced. Fairly irrelevant for your interface but, nevertheless, that is by-the-by.

Comment: Yellow boxes are ferrite beads

Comment: @Hari OK but can you see how the Q factor is affected by the parallel resistors now?

Comment: Q of a series RL circuit is given by Q =ωL/R = XL/R when R increases Q decreases.Why they are decreasing Q here

Comment: Look at the equation in my image and you'll see that as parallel R reduces, effective series R increases.

Comment: Thank you ,I got it. May I know what is the intention behind reducing the Q here

Comment: @Hari I expect it's to prevent excessive ringing when the circuit is powered up. The ringing could cause excessive voltages that might exceed the ratings on the chips used. But also, if the data is fairly square-edged, ringing could also cause problems with data corruptions.